# Blank page on some MySQL queries

Tags: php, mysql

My page is all blank because of this piece of code:

```
$coins = '2';                       
$vote_site = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';      
$account = $_POST['name']; 
$account = mysql_real_escape_string($account); 

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword) or die ('mySQL Connecting Error'); 
mysql_select_db($database); 
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 

if(isset($_POST['submit']) && strlen($account)>=4){
$search = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM account.account WHERE login = '$account' LIMIT 1");
    if (mysql_fetch_array($search) !== false){
    $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO account.account SET coins = "'.$coins.'" WHERE login = "'.$account.'"") or die(mysql_error);
    header("Location: http://' .$vote_site. '");
    }else{
        echo "Conta nao existe!";
        }
    }elseif (isset($_POST['submit']) && strlen($account)<4){
        echo "<font color='red'>Conta inválida!</font>";
    }
```

I have a html form, its supose to insert some values in a table and redirect to a website, but all I get is a white page.

I already tried all the ways to report errors, but it won't display anything!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: Enable error reporting.

Comment: @IMSoP already tried to do what it told me on that page, no errors

Comment: ok, tried to to move and something showed up:

    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''.$coins.'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)

Comment: Stop using `mysql_*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove double quotes around and concatenation dots here `SET coins = "'.$coins.'" WHERE` and here `login = "'.$account.'"")` :

```
$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO account.account SET coins = '$coins' WHERE login = '$account'") or die(mysql_error);
```

or switch their position:

```
$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO account.account SET coins = '".$coins."' WHERE login = '".$account."'") or die(mysql_error);
```

**OOOPS** Since this query is `INSERT` it has no sense to use `WHERE` so probably you've meant:

```
$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO account.account (coins, login) VALUES ('$coins', '$account')") or die(mysql_error);
```

**UPDATE 1** It seems you don't understand difference between `INSERT` and `UPDATE` statement for mysql. Read about [insert](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html)  and [update](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) please . And try:

```
$insert = mysql_query("UPDATE account.account SET coins = '$coins' WHERE login = '$account'") or die(mysql_error);
```

Probably that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''.$account.'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)

Comment: switching solved the above , but now:

(...)for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE login = 'xxxxxx'' at line 1

Comment: but I want to insert the variable coins where the account is the same as the person wrote

Comment: do you hear yourself? and understand the word `INSERT`? the logic way is to think and to decide before you start insertion :-) and you have to decide what exactly you plan to insert :-) you cant `INSERT ... WHERE` :-)

Comment: yes, but Im inserting a value that already exists : Duplicate entry 'account name' for key 'login'

Comment: so the question is WHAT is your goal? oh, I see, probably you need not `INSERT` but `UPDATE` ?

Comment: I want to insert "2" (in this case) on the row "coins" where the login is equal to what I typed